# Electron Windows Installer with wizard

Tags: node.js, electron

I have created an app using Electron and I want to create a Windows installer with a wizard.

I am currently using the electron-installer-windows module to create my installer. But this create a single .exe file with no wizard at all.

I need the wizard to allow user to select destination folder and the possibility of creating a desktop icon

So, there is a way to generate an installer with a wizard using this module? or I need to create my own installer?

also, will this installer manage dependency issues? for example if the end user does not have npm installed, or any other dependency

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up using Inno Setup to create the installer.

Answer (score 1):

I've had success with [electron-builder](https://www.npmjs.com/package/electron-builder). I would recommend giving it a try.

Comment: I tried with electron-builder and I got the same kind of installer without wizard.

Comment: The thing is that electron builder builds installers for windows, mac and linux. You can always just use a custom installer and build your own but you may find it a lot of work to do for each platform.

Comment: Yes, that is true, but in order to distribute this I need a more profesional look in my installer and I was not able to accomplish that using these tools :(

Comment: Seems to have an issue with a lot of files.